# How to generate all arrays whose elements are within two bounds specified by arrays in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose that two integer arrays `min` and `max` are given and they have equal `shape`. How to generate all Numpy arrays such that `min[indices] <= ar[indices] <= max[indices]` for all `indices in np.ndindex(shape)`? I have looked at the Numpy array creation routines but none of them seem to do what I want. I considered also starting with the `min` array and looping over its indices, adding `1` until the corresponding entry in `max` was reached, but I want to know if Numpy provides methods to do this more cleanly. As an example, if

```
min = np.array([[0, 1],
                [2, 3]])
max = np.array([[0, 1],
                [3, 4]])
```

Then I would like to have as an output:

```
[np.array([[0, 1],
           [2, 3]]),
np.array([[0, 1],
           [3, 3]]),
np.array([[0, 1],
           [2, 4]]),
np.array([[0, 1],
           [3, 4]])]
```

The reason I want to do this is that I am coding some implementations of tabular RL methods and the most natural way to specify states and actions is by using arrays. However, I also need to implement Q-tables and I would ideally have these tables be represented by 2D matrices. I want to map the states and actions to indices and use those to acces the Q-table. I know I can write a multidimensional Q-table, but then the TF-Agents library I need to use runs some checks on the inputs that throw errors. In any case, by assumption, the tabular RL problems I would solve with this method are relatively small, so the bounds on the matrices will restrict the number of resultants.

Comment: Can you show a small example of some input arrays and your desired output?

Comment: That's gonna be whole lot of arrays. For example `mins = [0] * 100` and `maxs=[10]*100` would give you `11**100` arrays

Comment: @CoryKramer I added a small example.

Comment: @QuangHoang I edited my question. Essentially, by assumption, I will not need this function whenever it yields a whole lot of arrays (that would then be a different RL domain)

Comment: If you don't have many output arrays, then `itertools.product` might be a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work,
Also since `range` and `itertools.product` both  returns a generator it's memory efficient (O(1) space).

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
a = np.array([[0, 1],
                [2, 3]])
b = np.array([[0, 1],
                [3, 4]])
l, m = np.shape(a)
ranges = [range(i, j+1) for i, j in zip(a.ravel(), b.ravel())]
ans  = [np.array(value).reshape(l,m) for value in product(*ranges)]
print(ans)
```

**Output**

```py
[array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]]), array([[0, 1],
       [2, 4]]), array([[0, 1],
       [3, 3]]), array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for